# Apps script, transfer file ownership - Is it possible with super admin account?

Tags: google-apps-script

I've been researching on using apps script to transfer file owner from one user to another, for files that are not owned by the script account.  I saw posts with possible solutions using drive API, but is it possible to use DriveApp's file setOwner() to transfer a file's ownership  when using a super admin account?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Apps Script doesn't support domain-wide authority for Drive Access. You'll need to use [Drive SDK and Service Accounts](https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation) for that.

Please log an enhancement in Apps Script [Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues) if you want to track this with the team.